# Fastest way for object detection based on some colors in image by emgu or opencv

Tags: c#, opencv, object-detection, emgucv

I have a list of some certain colors in array (about 60 different colors and they are not in a range), I want to detect them in images by Emgucv or opencv.
Actually I'm going to detect some objects by their colors and I don't want to do it through AI methods now.
Doing this through loop is very slow, I'm looking for fastest way.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in few steps:

1- convert you image to HSV domain simply by following code

```
Image<Hsv, byte> hsv = original.Convert<Hsv, byte>()
```

original is your image it maybe is in any image type.

2- filter you image:

```
   var m_Lower = new Hsv(mask.Hue - 5, mask.Satuation - 5, mask.Value - 5);
   var m_Higher = new Hsv(mask.Hue + 5, mask.Satuation + 5, mask.Value + 5);
   Image<Gray, byte> huefilter = hsv.InRange(m_Lower, m_Higher);
```

3- combine them, fastest way is to convert them to bitmap and save them (or not) then combine them

```
Bitmap img3 = new Bitmap(huefilter.Width, huefilter.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img3);
foreach (string file in files)
{
 img = new Bitmap(file);
 img.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
 g.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));
 }
```

files are the saved images